# Android gradle - gradle wrapper - distributionUrl get changed automatically after i edit it

Tags: android, ionic3

I'm trying to change gradle version from 4.1 to 4.4. When i change it manually and i execute "ionic cordova build android", the gradle version get back to 4.1 automatically.

I went to gradle-wrapper.propreties and i changed manually the distributionUrl.

from
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
to
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Expected results:
the app builds successfully.

Actual results:
the building process stops.

Error message:

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
>   Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\ghassen\Desktop\MyAppBeeMobile\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.4-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

The gradle version is set inside the `gradle-wrapper.jar` file itself (e.g. in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` among many other files) and the `distributionUrl` in the properties file doesn't take precedence.

Try upgrading the gradle version like so:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 4.4
```